# Generate PKCS12 with client certificate and self signed certificate's private key

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, self-signed, pkcs#12

I want to integarate with an third part API using 2 way SSL authentication. I have the public certificate provided by the third party. But I am facing problem in creating the PKCS12 file needed to call the API. Below is the process which I followed to create my self signed certificate and private key and use it with the public certificate provided to create a PKCS12 file

Creating request and private key
`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privatekey.key -out certificatereq.cer`

Creating Certificate using the request and key
`openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in certificatereq.cer -signkey privatekey.key -out selfsigned.crt`

Upon creation of certificate I used it to create PKCS12 file via below mentioned command
`openssl pkcs12 -export -in  selfsigned.crt -inkey privatekey.key -out outpkcs12file.p12 -name myname -CAfile thirdpartypublic.crt -caname mycaname -chain`

But on running the above mentioned command to create PKCS12 file I am getting error **Error self signed certificate getting chain**. I am new to SSL and two way authentication and not sure if using the openssl commands properly. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your private key and SSL certificate to a plain text file. The private key should go on top with the SSL certificate below (you have to keep that order).

Run the following openssl command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <Your_filename>.txt -out <Your_filename>.p12
```

You should be prompted for entering password after this.Enter your password and verify it in next prompt. The new PKCS12 file will be located within the directory from where the OpenSSL command was executed, if any location is not specified.

For reference: https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO25984.html